# insert dictionaries to a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, insert

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict1={'a':4,'d':2}
```

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
diclist=[{'b':3,'c':3},{'e':1,'f':1}]
```

As an output, I want to let dict1 be like this:

```
dict1={'a':4,'b':3,'c':3,'d':2,'e':1,'f':1}
```

so, I need to

1. compare dict1's values with diclist's value
2. if a value of a dict in diclist is smaller than the one of dict1, insert the dict to dict1
3. iterate 2 in diclist

This might be easy, however, if you are willing to help with this, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your keys in your example are all unique, how is it different from just merging all the dicts?

```
dict1 = {'a': 4, 'd': 2}
diclist = [{'b': 3, 'c': 3}, {'e': 1, 'f': 1}]
for d in diclist:
    dict1.update(d)
```

Here's a general approach. Consider providing more comprehensive examples in future

```
>>> dict1={'a':4,'d':2}
>>> diclist=[{'b':3,'c':3},{'e':1,'f':1}]
>>> 
>>> for d in diclist:
...  for k, v in d.items():
...   if k not in dict1 or v < dict1[k]:
...    dict1[k] = v
... 
>>> dict1
{'a': 4, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 1, 'd': 2, 'f': 1}
```

Comment: I think you need to implement a merge strategy to solve _if a value of a dict in diclist is smaller than the one of dict1, insert the dict to dict1_

Comment: @hd1 Merge strategies are necessary for ordered lists and collections (e.g. dictionaries.  The user specified what he wanted for a merge strategy in spec 2 when conflicts (same key between two merging dictionaries) occur.

Comment: You all seem to be missing my point that the example given has got all unique keys. So it's just a terrible example right? Shouldn't we expect people to provide _useful_ examples/testcases with their questions?

Comment: You're right, the example could be better.  But I still think it's worth implementing the spec that handles more general dictionaries if provided.  Either way, this and other answers are informative enough to get @Naoko to a correct answer.  BTW I wasn't the downvote.

Comment: @gnibbler Or addressing why the spec is unnecessary make sense...which you did after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in diclist:  # iterate over the dicts
    for k, v in d.items():  # iterate over the elements
         v2 = dict1.set_default(k, v)  # set the value if the key does not exist
                                       # and return the value (existing or newly set)
         if v < v2:  # compare with the existing value and the new value
             dict1[k] = v
```

This is probably most concise and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
In [15]: dict1={'a':4,'d':2}

In [16]: diclist=[{'b':3,'c':3},{'e':1,'f':1}]

In [17]: for dic in diclist:
    for key,value in dic.items():
        val=dict1.get(key,float("inf")) #fetch the value from dict1 if key is not found then return infinity
        if value < val:
            dict1[key] = value

In [18]: dict1
Out[18]: {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 1}
```